# Some questions on interdependence of some properties of abstract magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, magma

1. Does there exist a magma $(S,\cdot)$ such that for every $y\in S, \exists y'\in S$ such  that $x\cdot(y\cdot y')=x, \forall x,y\in S$, but there exist $x_1, x_2, x_3\in S$ such that $x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot x_3)\neq(x_2\cdot x_1)\cdot x_3$?
2. Does there exist a magma $(S,\cdot)$ such that for every $y\in S, \exists y'\in S$ such  that $x\cdot(y'\cdot y)=x, \forall x,y\in S$, but there exist $x_1, x_2, x_3\in S$ such that $x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot x_3)\neq(x_2\cdot x_1)\cdot x_3$?
3. Does there exist a magma $(S,\cdot)$ such that for every $a,b\in S$, $\exists x\in S$ such that $x\cdot a=b$, but there exist $x_1, x_2, x_3\in S$ such that $x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot x_3)\neq(x_2\cdot x_1)\cdot x_3$?

Answer (score 0):

The groupoids you described in 1. and 2. look somehow similar to (left/right) [*inverse property groupoids*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Inverse_properties), **but they are not the same**. I think is possible to find examples of non-associative magmas veryfying **exactly** your identities. I'll search and post if I find some.

---

We can say a bit more about 3.

A magma $(S,\cdot)$ such that $\forall\,a,b\in S$, $\exists!\,x\in S$ such that $x\cdot a=b$ is called *right quasigroup*.

A magma $(S,\cdot)$ such that $\forall\,a,b\in S$, $\exists!\,x\in S$ such that $a\cdot x=b$ is called *left quasigroup*.

If you change $\exists!$ to $\exists$ in the latter two, then right (left) translation on $S$ are not bijective but are only onto $S$. You call such structures *right/left division groupoid*.

In this article, [*On definitions of groupoids closely connected with quasigroups*](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/4094c08ca4da1ad0b79f8b06b1fad61b/basm61.pdf) by V.A. Shcherbacov, you find definitions of translations and definitions in such terms of some magmas you may be interested in.

---

**Addendum:**

Check pages 5-6 of this other paper, [*The varieties of quasigroups of bol-moufang type:
an equational reasoning approach* (Phillips-Vojtechovsky)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701715.pdf). This is **not yet what you ask** but gives you an overview of identities in magmas. I want to underline that those listed in this latter are properties *weaker* than associative, while - to do best - you should search instead properties related to left/right inverse property in non-associative groupoids. It is also important to specify *"in non-associative groupoids"* because, in groups, many identities similar to yours are trivial.

Post updates if you have any, I'll do the same!